# Can you restrict access to a realtime document?

Tags: google-drive-api

The sample app [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_sample) loads a file into a document and then very nicely keeps the document synchronized across all instances of the app.  Awesome!

I don't understand when a user is allowed access to the realtime document.  The load / save to the drive file is clearly regulated by permissions, but it seems that if I have the key to a realtime document I can make whatever changes I like to that document.  Another user, who *is* allowed to save to the drive file, can get evil updates to the realtime doc and might naively save them to the backing file.

I've tested this briefly by removing access to a file and verifying that the blocked user can indeed still change the realtime document even after access to the drive file is blocked.

Does anyone know a way to block updates to the realtime document from someone that doesn't have access to the relatively-offline file?

Additionally, I'd like to give each collaborator private space in the document that other collaborators cannot affect.  Does anyone know of plans for per-key permissions like Firebase supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to a Realtime file **is** restricted with sharing and permissions rights *exactly the same way as regular Drive files*. No user can modify it if they do not have access.

You can achieve the private collaborators part by having a separate private file. If this is not what you require, please give additional details.

Comment: Oh, ok - I must have been confused about what was happening.  Re. separate files: what I want is to allow people to make changes in certain areas of the document but not others - like a comment area but more full-fledged than comments.  I think I can move forward by just enforcing that in the UI but it would be nice to actually enforce it on the document.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: I have put in a feature request for collaborative object permissions, not sure how this will pan out. For now you would have to have 2 document models and set the isReadOnly flag to true so only the owner can make changes.